# SQL71501:has an unresolved reference to Schema [win]

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I am getting a unresolved reference in a SQLProject, the error occurs on the create line. All objects are causing it because they are all being created in a specific schema.
For example I have Table that is being created in a specific schema"win"
Create Table [win].[DataSource]. The error occurs because of the attempt to create it in the "win" schema If I remove the schema from the create statement the error goes away. The database project is a composite project including all of the artifacts (stored procs, tables, views...) from the win schema. Here is an example of the error I am seeing.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       SQL71501: Procedure: [win].[SelectCandidateExamSearch] has an unresolved reference to Schema [win].

Comment: Have you tried creating script with Build Action: build CREATE SCHEMA [win] ?

Comment: I have actually and that turned out to solve my problem. I did not have a create schema statement. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create script with Build Action: build with the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [win]
```

where [win] is the schema name.

For any database project in VS to build sucessfully, **ALL its references** must exist in the scope of the project and be valid.